# group and summarize by a variable inside a function

Tags: r, plyr

How can I group by a variable and summarize using ddply?

For example:

```
library(plyr)

sample <- function(x, g){
  print(g)
  print(x[[g]])
  res = ddply(x, ~x[[g]], summarise, value = mean(value))
  return(res)
}

x = data.frame(type = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b'), 
               age = c(20, 21, 21, 10), 
               value = c(100, 120, 121, 150))
sample(x = x, g = 'age')
```

Will fail saying:

```
 Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x,  : 
  object 'g' not found
```

Even though that function prints:

```
[1] "age"
[1] 20 21 21 10
```

Why can R find `g` when it comes to printing but not when it comes to `group_by`ing?

EDIT:
I would expect the output to be:

```
  x[["age"]] value
1         10 150.0
2         20 100.0
3         21 120.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `dplyr` package. 
In order to properly evaluate the group_by function I needed to use the `group_by_` which will be deprecated.

```
library(dplyr)

x = data.frame(type = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b'), 
               age = c(20, 21, 21, 10), 
               value = c(100, 120, 121, 150))

sample <- function(x, g){
  print(g)
  print(x[[g]])
  res<- group_by_(x, g) %>% summarise( mean(value))
  #res = ddply(x, ~x[[g]], summarise, value = mean(value))
  return(res)
}

sample(x = x, g = 'age')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is for the environment setted by '=' try calling your function this way

```
sample(x = x, g <- 'age')
```

or you can use simply

```
# g insted of ~x[[g]]
res = ddply(x, g, summarise, value = mean(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use tidyeval that came with the latest `dplyr` release:

```
sample <- function(x, g){
var <- dplyr::enquo(g)
res = x %>% group_by(!!var) %>% summarise(age_mean = mean(value))
return(res)
}

x = data.frame(type = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b'), 
           age = c(20, 21, 21, 10), 
           value = c(100, 120, 121, 150))
sample(x, age)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
     age age_mean
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1    10    150.0
2    20    100.0
3    21    120.5
```